# Google recaptcha dont work in second time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I have login Form , and Added Google reCAPTCHA in it,
first time you want to sign in ,it works correctly , but not for second time,
for example when login fails , it does not work to relogin , I mean when you click its checkbox the spinners just turn and nothing happen , and no error or warning shown .

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have wrote ASP for Back and two front with MVC and vuejs and Both of them have same Problem
and also in the way that when login fails it reset Google reCAPTCHA  .
I also record video you can see it to fully understand [enter link description here][2]

I found out when user click checkbox api request does not send and i dont know why
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN206.jpg
[2]: https://youtu.be/4C5RwFHAzRw

Comment: check for javascript errors on your page

Comment: Can you please specify the version of the reCaptcha, 
even if reCaptcha v1 Recaptcha.reload();
reCaptcha v2 Recaptcha.reset(); please check these things

Comment: Recaptcha is version 2 ,

Comment: there are no javascript error or warnings

Comment: i have wrote code in the way that after unsuccessfull SignIn it resets reCaptcha , and i dont know why it works good at first time but not in second